# Tracking upload progress of iCloud files

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, icloud

I'm writing a Unity plugin which makes use of iCloud.

Now the way I currently use to move files to iCloud is using this code:

```
     [byteDocument saveToURL:savePathURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
     {
         if (ubiquitousContainerURL != nil)
         {
             NSURL *ubiquityDocumentDirectory = [ubiquitousContainerURL
                                                 URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
                                                 isDirectory:YES];

             ubiquityDocumentDirectory = [ubiquityDocumentDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", filename, extension]];

             NSFileManager* fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                 NSError* error = nil;

                 if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:ubiquityDocumentDirectory.path])
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Attemping to move to cloud");
                     didMoveToCloud = [fm setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:savePathURL destinationURL:ubiquityDocumentDirectory error:nil];
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Attemping to replace in cloud");
                     didMoveToCloud = [fm replaceItemAtURL:ubiquityDocumentDirectory withItemAtURL:savePathURL backupItemName:nil options:0 resultingItemURL:nil error:&error];
                 }

                 if (didMoveToCloud)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Did move text document successfully to cloud");
                     //UnitySendMessage("GameObject", "DidSaveFile", [savePathURL.path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Failed to move text document to cloud");
                     //UnitySendMessage("GameObject", "DidSaveFile", [savePathURL.path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
                 }

                 if (error != nil)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Error saving text document to cloud: %@", error.description);
                     //UnitySendMessage("GameObject", "DidSaveFile", [savePathURL.path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
                 }
             });
         }
     }];
```

Basically I'm just using a simple inherited class of *UIDocument* called *CloudByteDocument*. I first save it locally on the device and then move it to iCloud afterwards.

Now the problem is that using ***SetUbiquituos*** does not seem to provide any way of tracking the upload progress? I'm already attached to both *MSMetaDataQuery* observerser, that is:

```
 // Listen for the second phase live-updating
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(queryDidReceiveNotification:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification object:nil];

// Listen for the first phase gathering
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(queryIsDoneGathering:) name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And I also realize that you can get things like upload and download progress during the *NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification*, however this update method doesn't seem to provide very reliable results all the time.

I was wondering if there is any way in which you can use an actual callback method to notify you when a file has been uploaded to iCloud? Or is the *NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification* method the standard way of doing so?

Any hints and help would be appriciated :)

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: See the docs for `NSMetaDataItem` and `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentUploadedKey` and `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentDownloadedKey`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that you can retrieve these numbers from NSMetaDataItem, perhaps I should have mentioned that in the post :) My question was aimed at if this is the only way to figure out when a file has been uploaded? That is, using *NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification* coupled with the *NSMetaDataItem* key.

Comment: Can you give a Flow level example how to achieve this I am struggling this to store and restore a Core Data Sqlite file from custom filter. I don't want to do conventional method of Core Data with iCloud but thought my code like wahtsapp.

Comment: @rmaddy I check the suggestion and also some docs but there is no clear tutorial or understand how this is achieved and i am unable to get the percentage than till getting is uploaded 0---1 but not 0.1,0.2...., can you help with an example. I am using iOS 7 onwards and Xcode 7 just FYI

Comment: @VickyDhas Have you got any success in making the progress similar to whatsApp progress of backup the chat to iCloud? please answer here, if you have something to share https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274400/how-to-check-the-progress-of-the-items-being-uploaded-to-icloud

Comment: What I learnt from there was that iCloud zipping file contents and extraction to consolidate files and expand is what whatsapp showing as progress bar. Not the icloud upload. As u may try to backup your huge video and image BU of whatsapp to icloud.  download whatsapp on other phone and restore. If you ahve quit wahtsapp or phone on device 1 the other device will extract corrupt images. This concluded iCloud is always in background with its own time and priority to BU.