# How to check the progress of the items being uploaded to iCloud

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, icloud

I have implemented the backup system like we have in WhatsApp.

1. First, it is checking for the document directory and zip the data to temporary directory.
2. Then get the url to iCloud

   ```
   func getUrlToiCloud() -> URL? {
   let fileManager = FileManager.default
   let url = fileManager.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)
   return url
   }
   ```
3. Next is to backup the items to iCloud

   ```
   func iCloudBackupHandler(_ backupName: String, backupPath: String) {
   guard let url = getUrlToiCloud()  else {
       return
   }

   let loggedInUser: String
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       loggedInUser = CKCurrentUserDefaultName
   } else {
       loggedInUser = CKOwnerDefaultName
   }
   print("loggedInUser:\(loggedInUser)")
   let localBackupUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: backupPath)
   let iCloudDocumentUrl = url.appendingPathComponent(backupName)
   print("Local:\(localBackupUrl)")
   print("iCloudDocumentUrl:\(String(describing: iCloudDocumentUrl))")
   do {
       try FileManager.default.replaceItem(at: iCloudDocumentUrl, withItemAt: localBackupUrl, backupItemName: backupName, options: .withoutDeletingBackupItem, resultingItemURL: nil)
      //try FileManager.default.setUbiquitous(true, itemAt: localBackupUrl, destinationURL: iCloudDocumentUrl)
   } catch {
       print("error while backup: \(error)")
   }
   }
   ```

   My question is here, on the following line. which backups the item to iCloud.

   ```
    try FileManager.default.replaceItem(at: iCloudDocumentUrl, withItemAt: localBackupUrl, backupItemName: backupName, options: .withoutDeletingBackupItem, resultingItemURL: nil)
   ```

How can I track the progress of the file being uploaded to iCloud? As in WhatsApp there is a progress(percentage) of the file being backed up. Please let me know, if you have idea on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update progress bar during copy file with NSFileManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544145/update-progress-bar-during-copy-file-with-nsfilemanager)

Comment: Might be better to use `URLSessionDownloadTask`, that way you have a way to determine progress. You also have the ability to make it a long running task and do things without blocking the main thread. Also allows download when app is in background mode

Comment: That's true for the download part, but this is related to iCloud upload progress. it will have some different approach. may be like the link reference by @Larme in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let say, You already have fileUrl.

```
     do {
                   
            let fileValues = try fileURL?.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.ubiquitousItemIsUploadingKey])
//Please add more checks for error, success too
if fileValues?.ubiquitousItemIsUploading == true {
   if let fileProgress = fileItem?.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataUbiquitousItemPercentUploadedKey) as? Double {
        print("uploaded percent ---", fileProgress)
     }
  } 
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("backupError"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```